# Trouble with fetching from core data and putting in array

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, core-data

I'm trying to make a list within core data that can add to an entity "Person" two attributes: age(Int16) and name(string). As far as I can tell i believe it is storing new objects as new ones are added but I dont think my array is fetching them properly. Can someone help me figure where I'm going wrong.

```
    var list = [Person(context:context)]

@IBAction func saveButton(_ sender: Any)
{
    list.append(Person(context:context))

    list[list.count-1].age = Int16(ageTF.text!)!

    list[list.count-1].name = nameTF.text

    let newList = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject (forEntityName: "Person",into: context) as NSManagedObject

    newList.setValue(list[list.count-1].name, forKey: "name")
    newList.setValue(list[list.count-1].age, forKey: "age")

    appDelegate.saveContext()
}

@IBAction func printList(_ sender: Any)
{

    for index in 0...list.count-1
    {
        print("Name of person # \(index) = \(list[index].name!)")
        print("Age of person # \(index) = \(list[index].age)")
    }

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Person")

    do {
        let results = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
        let listItems = results as! [NSManagedObject]

        print(listItems)
    }
    catch {
        print("Error")

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The range in your for loop is `0...0` try `0..<list.count`

Comment: I had the loop like this before I just changed while troubleshooting. Changed it back on post.

Answer (score 0):

`Person(context:context)` is functionally the same as `NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject (forEntityName: "Person",into: context) as NSManagedObject` so you are inserting the object twice into core data.